# AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'OptionMenu'

Tags: python, optionmenu, customtkinter

Does someone know, why I get this error?
I've imported `import customtkinter` and get this error:

AttributeError: module 'customtkinter' has no attribute 'OptionMenu'

when executing this piece of code:

```
optionmenu = customtkinter.CTkOptionMenu(over_frame, values=["", "", ""])
optionmenu.pack(pady=12, padx=10)
optionmenu.set("CTkOptionMenu")
```

Comment: It's only a problem in PyCharm, not in Spyder

Comment: I think I know the answer, PyCharm has the newest version installed and the others have an older version which contains the OptionMenu module, while the newest hasn't. Why has Tom Schimansky not replaced it? Nor give an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

try this at terminal?

```
py -m pip install --upgrade customtkinter
```